# Post Base64 image to Mvc controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Consider this base64 encode image

```
<img src='data:image/Png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABICAYAAABhlHJbAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAEZ0FNQQAAsY8L/GEFAAAACXBIWXMAABVlAAAVZQGF3cVdAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB3d3cuaW5rc2NhcGUub3Jnm+48GgAABnNJREFUeF7tnFls3EQYx11ucQshClWbtb1LC4RLIARIHAXxgsQDCOWhJGs7mypIoII4BAIhsYAEWY+TlEo8FAQSQjxAuR54AnFUFHH0CQlEEWcaQhpKmx5poVWb8H3eb92Jd7Nre8a7a2d/0l9txvN99vw1HnvtGSsdqskYzu2ayb4A7dNN9oNm2E8qPW8fT5s71EOznDwYdxQ0x0s12LtXD248kaoFpFg8TisMX6Gb9t264dwHSR5PtEz7Mc10BrE92b6RnKLMLaGWulDPO+w3ryLoje8FMlG37As1094IQX/7k6RJqsl+wdNz2WDxVDXProWyGX8dv+qamFu34WQwbz1UPOIPTLec3+HfndXltQU9+P0qE1Vr9GzY+K2/MugACAfUd8q9Mslir4M+BMO+oXb52xpYaOLq1cUTyLziKVCIJvGVtmYMdlf4gTMZ4NkGpjq+NoeTwZ51k8EA+zS/AcaG5z13U0o2zy6FtoqO8ZNKpm/0AvgP350Z7SO1kHlTXJujalqB3vZApQCvSti1aT+pJGcOdUNbZZiHegtP308qBXCJfoL2k0q6+p1LYNzbwRkgoumca />
```

I would like to post this src to Mvc controller but getting null when post with ajax here is the post method.

```
    var file = document.getElementById("base64image").src;

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("base64image", file);

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:26792/home/SaveImage",
            type: "POST",
            data: file



        });
```

**Mvc Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]

    public void SaveImage(Image file)
    {

    }
```

I think the datatype I am using is not valid for this please suggest me what can I do here.

[image]

**Full Html Code**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>WebcamJS Test Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }
    h2, h3 { margin-top:0; }
    form { margin-top: 15px; }
    form > input { margin-right: 15px; }
    #results { float:right; margin:20px; padding:20px; border:1px solid; background:#ccc; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>

<h1>WebcamJS Test Page</h1>
<h3>Demonstrates simple 320x240 capture &amp; display</h3>

<div id="my_camera"></div>

<!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../webcam.min.js"></script>

<!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
</script>

<!-- A button for taking snaps -->
<form>
    <input type=button id="takeshot" value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
</form>

<!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
<script language="JavaScript">

    window.onload = function () {

        setInterval(function () { take_snapshot() }, 5000);
    }
    function take_snapshot() {
        // take snapshot and get image data
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            // display results in page
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
                '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' + 
                '<img id="base64image" src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
        });



        var file = document.getElementById("base64image").src;

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("base64image", file);

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:26792/home/SaveImage",
            type: "POST",
            data: file



        });
        //var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //ajax.addEventListener("load", function (event) { uploadcomplete(event); }, false);
        //ajax.open("POST", "http://localhost:26792/home/SaveImage");

        //ajax.send(formdata);
    }
    </script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: To start with, Is that a valid base64 string of an image ? Can you create a jsfiddle with that which render an image ?

Comment: @Shyju this is a valid image I just removed some characters for security reasons please help.I dont want to show real image I mean.

Comment: The src is too long to write here so I used short example

Comment: @DumpsterDiver how about using string as the data type? then you can convert that base64 string as image in you controller

Comment: @Niladri its also receiving null

Comment: But i can see the complete src when alert or use console.log

Comment: @DumpsterDiver what is the content type in ajax call? can you post the full code

Comment: Please see the edit changing of params will not work because if this would be a case i would not receive a hit to controller.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***I am not 100 % sure what your end goals are here. But the below answer explains how you can send a base64 image source string to server and save it. I tested it with a base64 string generated from a [small image (22 KB size)](http://jsbin.com/leqolagowo/1/edit?html,output) and it worked.***

In your ajax call, you should be sending the `FormData` object you created, not the value of `file` variable. Also make sure you use `processData` and `contentType` properties when making the ajax call while sending a FormData object.

```
var file = document.getElementById("base64image").src;

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("base64image", file);

$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SaveImage")",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

Now since this is the base 64 string of the image, use `string` as the parameter type of your action method. The parameter name should match with your formdata item key(`base64Image`). You can generate a byte array from the base64 string in your action method. Also the image source starts with `data:image/png;base64,` which needs to be removed from the string before you try to convert it.

The below method accepts the string you are sending from the client, and removes the first 21 characters and use the result of that (which is now a valid base 64 string) and then creates an image from that and saves to `Content/Images/` directory in the app root with a random file name.

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveImage(string base64image)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64image))
        return;

    var t = base64image.Substring(22);  // remove data:image/png;base64,

    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(t);

    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    var randomFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) + ".png";
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), randomFileName);
    image.Save(fullPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

I am not 100 % sure that the default model binder can bind the base64 string to an image. If not, you can perhaps create one which does that and add that to the model binders in your system and then use the Image as the parameter type. The code inside model binder will be very similar ( read the string and generate image from that)

Comment: Sorry @Shyju its still null ,thankyou for taking interest thank you very much.

Comment: I actually used the exact same code in the answer and verified that it is working. Did you follow the answer as it is ? (both client side and server side)

Comment: You are calling SaveImage in ajax POST but the action is SaveImage2?

Comment: Yea. That is a typo. I will fix it

Comment: I was sending file instead of formdata thank you sooo much.

Comment: Regarding a Data URL (in form value) just split at the (first) comma when you're not interested (optional) mediatype. The syntax is `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Answer (score 1):

I am using HttpPostedFileBase.cs.

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult AddDocument(ReservationDocumentsVM reservationDocumentsVM, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
            {
                if (postedFile != null)
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Documents/");

                    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    }
                    postedFile.SaveAs(path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));
                    reservationDocumentsVM.VirtualPath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

                    reservationRepository.AddOrUpdateReservationDocuments(reservationDocumentsVM);


                }


   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Reservation");
        }
```

Comment: what is reservationDocumentsVM in this context? I am not passing two arguments.