# Send a base64 image from View to a ASP.NET Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to send a base64 image from a View to a Controller.

I have the base64 stored in an input and I get it like this (working fine):

```
var photoBase64Captured = $('#txtPhotoBase64Captured').val();
```

Then in my `View`, I call the `Controller` and wait for a response:

```
$.get("@Url.Action("CheckFace", "User")", { base64: photoBase64Captured }, function (data) {

   var result = $.parseJSON(data);

   if (data != null) {

   }
});
```

When I try to call the Controller, I'm getting the following error in Chrome's console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

This is the `Controller`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CheckFace(string base64)
{

}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Is the base64 too long to send to the `Controller`?

If I send other values to the Controller it works fine, so it is not a problem of the method.

Comment: Looks like Chrome issue, did you try another browser? Another possible issue is using `$.get()`, because sending (large) data to service should be done using `POST` request, with data in the body of request. Could you provide the code of corresponding controller's method?

Comment: @perozzo , check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863910/post-base64-image-to-mvc-controller

Comment: @apdevelop done!

Comment: @perozzo, Is it `GET` or `POST` controller action? Looks like you're exceeding limits of `GET` request (url length). Try the solution suggested above by @ray with `POST` request.

Comment: @apdevelop it's a GET since I'll not post anything, just return the result on the controller back to the view.

Comment: @perozzo - there is *sending* (presumably large) data to controller too, the `base64` parameter. Not the application area of `GET` requests.

Comment: @apdevelop sorry, don't understand what you just said

Comment: @perozzo In brief, it's proper to use `POST` request for this task with data in its body instead of `GET`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166104/discussion-between-perozzo-and-apdevelop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use post for in this case. Image base64 to large for Get request.

```
$.post("@Url.Action("CheckFace", "User")", { base64: photoBase64Captured }, function (data) {

   var result = $.parseJSON(data);

   if (data != null) {

   }
});

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CheckFace(string base64)
{

}
```